# How can I (safely) divide a maximum value, resulting in a floating point value?

Tags: c++, max, division

I want to calculate conversion factors. For this I have to divide the maximum value of e.g. ushort by the maximum value of uchar.

I want to do this dynamically, by passing a parameter into a function or  a typename. Then I want to select the max values and perform the calculation.

There are two problems:

1. How do I dynamically select the max value?
2. How can I safely divide the two values?

All values are known to fit into the range of double.

Ideally I would want to do something like:

```
double x = numeric_limits<T>::max / numeric_limits<T2>::max;
```

However that is not correct/possible.

Comment: sizeof() tells you how big they are, and that STRONGLY IMPLIES the max value that could ever be stored in that number of bytes.

Comment: Why is `double x = numeric_limits<T>::max / numeric_limits<T2>::max;` not correct or possible?

Comment: @MarcB I need accurate results.

Comment: @NathanOliver because it throws an error. Apparently it is an enumeration that cannot be used in an arithmetic expression. If anybody knows how to properly do it, I would be happy.

Comment: Well `max` is a function so you need `double x = numeric_limits<T>::max() / numeric_limits<T2>::max();` for it to actually compile.  Why not post a [mcve] of what you tried and the errors it had?

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh dear ... you are right :)
Is the division ok as long as the resulting data type fits, e.g. in a double?

Comment: You could lose precision trying to store a `long long` in a double.  Although if you convert either operand of the division into a `double` it should be okay.

Comment: @NathanOliver perfect. Would you like to write the answer or should I?

Comment: @John Looks like flatmouse just did.  Just go with that if it is acceptable to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed idea should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template <typename T, typename T2>
double get_ratio()
{
    return static_cast<double>(std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) / std::numeric_limits<T2>::max();
}

int main()
{
    auto ratio = get_ratio<unsigned short, unsigned char>();
    std::cout << ratio << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67ddea0cefad5a2e)

Comment: So close, but that happens if I stare to long at my monitor. Thanks!